# Count with group by, return number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a count query that requires a group by. But when I get my results I am getting the correct amount of rows but with their tally in the total column instead of the amount of rows which is what I want.

```
SELECT Count(p.products_id) AS total 
FROM   products p 
       LEFT JOIN specials s 
              ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN manufacturers m 
              ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
       JOIN products_description pd 
         ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       JOIN products_to_categories p2c 
         ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
       INNER JOIN products_specifications ps7 
               ON p.products_id = ps7.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN products_to_icon p2i 
              ON p.products_id = p2i.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN products_icons pi 
              ON p2i.icons_id = pi.icons_id 
WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
       AND pd.language_id = '1' 
       AND ps7.specification IN ( 'Polycotton' ) 
       AND ps7.specifications_id = '7' 
       AND ps7.language_id = '1' 
GROUP  BY p.products_id
```

What can I do to make it give me the total rows, instead of grouping the totals of each product ID as total.

Sample of what I am getting:

```
total
1
2
1
1
2
2
```

What I want:

```
total
6
```

Comment: Can the current count contain 0? And if so should the total count include that row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
Count(t.products_id) AS total FROM (
    SELECT p.products_id
    FROM   products p 
           LEFT JOIN specials s 
                  ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
           LEFT JOIN manufacturers m 
                  ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
           JOIN products_description pd 
             ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
           JOIN products_to_categories p2c 
             ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
           INNER JOIN products_specifications ps7 
                   ON p.products_id = ps7.products_id 
           LEFT JOIN products_to_icon p2i 
                  ON p.products_id = p2i.products_id 
           LEFT JOIN products_icons pi 
                  ON p2i.icons_id = pi.icons_id 
    WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
           AND pd.language_id = '1' 
           AND ps7.specification IN ( 'Polycotton' ) 
           AND ps7.specifications_id = '7' 
           AND ps7.language_id = '1' 
    GROUP  BY p.products_id
 )t
```

This will include rows that first would have returned a 0...

If you don't want that, then add this line under the `GROUP BY` line:

```
HAVING count(p.products_id) > 0
```

Option 2:
Just use the php function `mysql_num_rows()`, `mysqli_num_rows()` or the PDO equivalent, depending on which set of mysql functions you are using. (This option is not advised, as it has needless overhead for the server.)

Comment: What is this "needless overhead" of which you speak?

Comment: @TML The needless overhead in option2 is that Mysql will actually return multiple rows to PHP, so PHP then can determine how many rows it is. In option 1 Mysql will return just 1 row with the count in it.

Comment: I see what you mean; I interpreted the question as him wanting BOTH the individual rows *and* a row count. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: I ended up using distinct, with no group by which accomplished what I wanted. (since I didn't really need to group, if I was only going for the count). Also someone else posted to do that, but removed their answer

Answer (score 0):

Nest everything in a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
      [your query here]
) AS subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///group-by-modifiers.html)

```
GROUP  BY p.products_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Edit: I'm assuming you are using MySQL. Other DBMSs have a different syntax:

```
GROUP  BY p.products_id, rollup(p.SOME_COLUMN);
```

Comment: It will the always the last result, in your case, 9... To be sure, you should select another column `SELECT p.products_id, COUNT(p.products_id)`. Then the column p.products_id will be `NULL`. Try it...